# Convert positive lookahead regex to negative lookahead one?

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++

as the title goes, I want to change the script containing positive lookahead into negative one.

my script is

`^[^\S\n]*\n(?=[^\n]*\S)`
of course it needs to be identical in search task.

the reason to do this is my text editor does not allow replace one by one task for script containing positive lookahead, instead it only allows replace-all.

Comment: What is your regex trying to achieve?

Comment: @niet it finds and cuts off one blank line (including the line with space and tab)  before unblank one.

Comment: And why does replace-all not suit your needs?

Comment: hmm I prefer to double check before final replacement to avoid mistake, so turning pos LA to neg LA isn't possible in this case?

Comment: Double-checking is what backups and version control are for. If you're doing a big search-and-replace without a backup, that's kind of a red flag.

Comment: Try this: `^[^\S\n]*\n(?!\n*\s)`

Comment: @niet probably you're right but I always back up my files before making changes so this is just my personal preference when editing text one at a time.  @ alireza that was the first I've tried , but it's not identical at all(grammatically speaking)

Comment: Your regex is somehow hard to read because of [obnoxious](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html#obnoxious). As you're using notepad++ (pcre), you might want to use `\h` for horizontal space: `^\h*\n(?=\h*\S)` (I can read that better) - to invert the pos. lookahead to neg.: strip blank line if there is NOT a blank line ahead: `^\h*\n(?!\h*$)` but I'm still not sure, if I understand question as meant :p